# Struggling with large code base in c++

Tags: c++

I know basic concepts like copy constructor and other of c++ like below example

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
   Test() {}
   Test(const Test &t)
   {
      cout<<"Copy constructor called "<<endl;
   }
   Test& operator = (const Test &t)
   {
      cout<<"Assignment operator called "<<endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
  Test t1, t2;
  t2 = t1;
  Test t3 = t1;
  getchar();
  r

eturn 0;
}
```

Now when when I am trying to understand the code flow of the project in my office but i am struggling in that. I am not able to figure out how the flow is going.Sometime i am getting some overview but when i dig into the code i m not connecting the c++ concepts to the real code .

Comment: Figuring out the flow of any non-toy OO program is a challenge for most people, even with years of experience. Ask your colleagues to explain how things fit together. Don't try to grasp everything at once (if it's a large program it's possible that you never will).

Comment: My first suggestion is to make sure that you are using a good editor/IDE that allows you to jump between usages, definitions and declarations. I have also found Doxygen useful, particularly when configured to dump everything.

Answer (score -1):

The code flow goes like this:

- `Test t1, t2` t1, t2 are going to be constructed, but there is no parameter provided, so default constructor is called, nothing output.
- `t2 = t1` operator = is called, output `Assignment operator called`
- `t3 = t1` t3 is going to be constructed, and t1 is provided as the parameter, so copy constructor is called, output `Copy constructor called`

Also, change `stdio.h` to `cstdio`, C++ use `cstdio` instead of `stdio.h`